# Debugging: Unable to reveal the value of the TStrings

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

In my debugging, I tried to get Delphi to reveal or expose the value of FTestResult (TStrings). The Delphi's debugger shows in  "FTestResult     ()" in watch window.

```
private
FTestThread:TTestThread;
FTestState:TState;
FTestResult:TStrings; //represent a list of strings.
........
........
FTestResult.Clear();
FTestResult.Add('EmployeeId=''' + TMainForm(Application.MainForm).UserId.Text + '''');
........
```

Is this normal if it produces nothing in () after add?

Please advise... Thanks

Comment: It is normal behavior. Debug visualizer for `TStrings` content was added in more recent version of Delphi.

Comment: You can see it if you put FTestResult.Text (all in 1 line, like a string) or FTestResult[0] for first result, FTestResult[1] for second, and soon

Comment: In the debugger, put the cursor at FTestResult, right click and invoke "evaluate/modify" - type FTestResult.Text into the expression window and hit evaluate. You will see the values in the window underneath. If you want individual values, use FTestResult[index];

Answer (score 3):

> Is this normal if it produces nothing in `()` after calling `Add`?

Yes this is the expected behaviour. Delphi 7 does not have a bespoke debugger visualizer for `TStrings`. This functionality was added in Delphi 2010. You'll have to find some other way to inspect the contents of this object in Delphi 7.

The `()` is the output of the standard visualizer for an instance of a class. Inside the parens are the data members, of which `TStrings` has none.